# intersection of antisymetric relations is antisymetric

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Suppose $A$ is some set, and $R$ and $S$ are relations on $A$ s.t. $R$ and $S$ are anti-symmetric. I want to prove that $R\cap S$ is anti-symmetric.

Let $a,b \in A \ $ s.t. $a\ne b$ and $(a,b)\in R\cap S$ then, $(a,b)\in R$ and $(a,b)\in S$ so $(b,a)\notin R$ and $(b,a) \notin S$ so $(b,a)\notin R\cap S$

Is this correct? I feel its weird to prove it from the direct definition of anti-symmetry ($a\sim b \wedge b\sim a \implies a=b$).

Comment: If you want to show that $R \cap S$ is anti-symmetric if $R$ and $S$ are, then you should change the title to "intersection of...".

Comment: great idea thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is anti-symmetric then any subset of $R$ is anti-symmetric, also $R\cap S$.

I think the normal way of doing such things is:

If $(a,b),(b,a)\in R\cap S\implies (a,b),(b,a)\in R\implies a=b$.

Comment: my question is for affirmation, or not, of my method.

Comment: @z b: And my answer affirm your solution and give a hint about the method.

Comment: I am confused. If my answer is valid, then why would you assume that I would want some other method? I did learn from your comment, that every subset of our relation is a anti-symmetric, but in no way do I see any method for proving it, or a hint at such a method. So if your answer to my question is "yes", then I am satisfied:)

Comment: @z b: Yes, your proof is valid, but you made more than "needed".